# vba code not doing INSERT into database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am very new to access. I was told that the way to do a database insert in access is with the CurrentDb object (as long as the table is in the same database, and it is in my case.) I made this code, have no errors, but it doesn't do the insert.

```
Private Sub Add_Delete_Click()

Dim query As String
query = "Insert Into tbl_Inventory_History (InventoryID, Modification_Date, Change)"
query = query & "Values (" & Me.InventoryID & ",#" & Now() & "#," & Me.Quantity & ")"
CurrentDb.Execute query
End Sub
```

This code is run on a button click in the Inventory form page. I want it to insert any changes made to the inventory on the inventory history page. I made sure the the tbl_Inventory_History does exist and is spelled correctly. What is the issue?

Comment: Try adding dbFailOnError to your execute statement  `CurrentDb.Execute query, dbFailOnError`   Perhaps you are violating an integrity constraint with your insert

Comment: Have you tried using a stop/break and then F8 to step through while printing in the immediate window?  This helps to see what the query is doing.  Or have you tried explicitly calling your DB from a recordset just to see if that works?

Comment: What I typically see is DoCmd.RunSQL(query). I'd try the suggestion from @Scotch first though. Sounds like a cleaner solution. With RunSQL you have to manage the currendb and warnings settings.

Comment: @Scotch, what does adding the dbFailOnError line do? I added it in and nothing happened.

Comment: @TkEyi60, I am very new to Access, can you elaborate on exactly what you are describing?

Comment: And, i can't see how I am violating integrity. I have a very simple database, and my Inventory History table is child to the Inventory table (joined on the InventoryID)

Comment: Sure.  On the left of your vba code you can click a line and make a red dot.  This will stop your code and you can watch it step piece by piece each time you hit F8.  So break it near the top.  And to view immediate press CTRL+G.  When you use `Debug.Print query` it will print out at the bottom.

Comment: Can you do as TKE suggested, and in the Immediate window type "?query" (without the quotes) and then copy and paste here what the program thinks the variable "query" is equal to?  It will help us make suggestions.

Comment: Where is Debug.Print query supposed to print out? I don't see anything printed anywhere... By the way, when in debug mode, when you hover over the last line, it says dbFailOnError =128. What does this mean?

Comment: @user1015214 The dbFailOnError would throw you a runtime error if you were violating a constraint (assuming you had setWarnings to true).  Does adding a semicolon at the end of your query string make a difference? I don't recall if it's necessary

Comment: The semi-colon doesn't make a difference. Also, I took off the referential integrity between the two tables and got the same error. Note: even when the dot is at the query= line (not the ConnectDB line), when I hover over dbFailOnError I still see that it's equal to 128. So, the error seems to come before the ConnectDb line?...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of "gluing together" a SQL statement, you might find it more convenient in this case to add the record by using a Recordset, like this

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_Inventory_History", dbOpenTable)
rst.AddNew
rst!InventoryID = Me.InventoryID
rst!Modification_Date = Now()
rst!Change = Me.Quantity
rst.Update
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice! Recordset seems to be a much cleaner way of going about this (and it works!). However, it seems that my original code worked all along. I had the tbl_Inventory_History table open and never closed it. I thought that its data would be automatically updated on the screen, but I was incorrect... But thanks for the code, I'm replacing mine for yours.